# Content Assistance is not working for eclipse mars for maven projects only

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

In my eclipse (mars version), Content Assistance is not working for maven projects only. However, it is working properly for other Java project.

please let me know what needs to configure to enable it.

Comment: What exactly are the features that you are missing?

Comment: I was missing auto completion feature. It's resolved now. I have re-installed properly after removing registry.